# Variable scope issue with AngularJS promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am totally new on `AngularJS` and I try to figure out what's wrong with my code.

In general it looks that is a variable scope issue but I don't know how to solve it:

here is my code:

```
'use strict';

(
    function() {
        /**
         * @name angularApp.controller:LoginpageCtrl
         * @description This controller is responsible to manipulate the user login process.
         * @param themeConfigs Contains the site themeConfiguration options.
         */
        var $userRegisterCtrl = function ( $window, $timeout, user, themeConfigs ) {
            var $this = this;
            $this.theme_configs = themeConfigs;
            $this.username = '';
            $this.email = '';
            $this.password = '';
            $this.error = '';
            $this.success = '';

            $this.register = function() {
                user
                    .register(
                        $this.username,
                        $this.password,
                        $this.email
                    )
                    .then(
                        function( ) {
                            $this.success = 'Your account has been successfully created.<br />';
                            $this.success += 'Soon you will redirected in login page.';

                            $timeout(
                                function() {
                                    $window.location.href = '/#/login';
                                },
                                4000
                            );
                        },
                        function( $error_message ) {
                            console.log( $error_message );
                        }
                    );
            };
        };

        $userRegisterCtrl.$inject = [ '$window', '$timeout', 'user', 'themeConfigs' ];

        angular.module('angularApp' ).controller( 'userRegisterCtrl', $userRegisterCtrl );
    }
)();
```

and the error I get is the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'success' of undefined
    at register.js:27
    at processQueue (angular.js:14745)
    at angular.js:14761
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:15989)
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15800)
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:16097)
    at done (angular.js:10546)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:10744)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10685)
```

So the line 27 related with the following two lines:

```
$this.success = 'Your account has been successfully created.<br />';
$this.success += 'Soon you will redirected in login page.';
```

but why the $this.success is outside scope ? And how can I solve that issue ? Is there any trick related to `promisses`?

Comment: Why you use `this` in AngularJS? Why you don't use scope?

Comment: Also, why you name your variables with `$` at start? Usually, angularJS objects should be named this way

Comment: I use the controllers with `controllerAs` that's why I use the `this`. I have assign the `this` into `$this` because my `IDE` marked the `this` as out of scome in the promisse callback. I also try the `this` but doesn't work. :(

Comment: can you try renaming $this to _this? usually angular uses $ for its services and variables, and your problem has nothing to do with the scope variable but with $this not being defined

Comment: that was the problem !!! I just chang it and it worked :) Thanks ;) If you like place your comment as answer to upvote you :)

Comment: @Dayan + can you explain in your answer, why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try renaming $this to _this? usually angular uses $ for its services and variables,

- $index
- $id
- $this

all examples

Your problem has nothing to do with the scope variable but with $this not being defined.